# Economics simplification of stochastic transition of capital

Tags: logarithms, economics, stochastic-calculus

I'm taking an macro-econ paper and I can't seem to work out the following simplification. Basically somehow by combining equation `4.14` and `4.15` we get `4.16`.

$y_{t-1}$ denotes the previous year's output per capita, so $ln(y_{t-1})$ should be $a*ln(k_{t-1}) + ln(A)$, can't seem to explain the process even though I know the solution!

#### Equation 4.14

$$
ln(k_{t+1}) = b + a*ln(k_t) + ln(A_t)
$$

#### Equation 4.15

$$
ln(y_t) = a*ln(k_t) + ln(A_t)
$$

#### Equation 4.16

$$
ln(y_t) = ab + a*ln(y_{t-1}) + ln(A)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ln k_{t+1}\stackrel{(4.14)(4.15)}{=}b+\ln(y_t)\implies\ln(y_t)\stackrel{(4.15)}{=}a\cdot(b+\ln(y_{t-1}))+\ln(A_t)$$

Comment: Ahhh yep overlooked the first simplification that you made, thanks for your answer!